# Working of MatchQ[] with Blank, BlankSequence, BlankNullSequence

Tags: pattern-matching, debugging

This code:

```
In[76]:= Trace[MatchQ[{1,2,3}, {_?NumberQ}]]
```

gives:

> Out[76]= {MatchQ[{1,2,3},{_?NumberQ}],False}

---

This code:

```
In[77]:= Trace[MatchQ[{1,2,3}, {__?NumberQ}]]
```

gives:

> Out[77]= {MatchQ[{1,2,3},{__?NumberQ}],{NumberQ[1],True},{NumberQ[2],True},{NumberQ[3],True},True}

---

**Question:**

Why does `_?NumberQ` just gives *False* but `__?NumberQ` make actual comparrision *{NumberQ[1],True},{NumberQ[2],True},{NumberQ[3],True}*?

Comment: Which one is that you find surprising? `{1,2,3}` does not match `{_}` so further tests do not make sense.

Comment: @Kuba `Trace[]` just gives *False*. Why `Trace[]` does not shows that `MatchQ` tries to match but it did not match? Something like:  `{MatchQ[{1,2,3},{_?NumberQ}],{NumberQ[{1,2,3}],False},False}`?

Comment: No, not just `False`, `MatchQ[{1, 2, 3}, {_?NumberQ}]` too. and already this step fails because `{1,2,3}` is not a list of one element as `{_}` indicates. Compare with `Trace[MatchQ[{1, 2, 3}, _?NumberQ]]`

Comment: @Kuba. So `{_}` is for the list of 1 element, `{__}` is for any number of elements but not empty list, `{___}` is for any number of elements including empty list. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, check documentation examples in Blank, BlankSequence, BlankNullSequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)s and [Sjoerd Smits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit) comments helped to get the answer*

`_` matches any valid expression while `__` matches a sequence of expressions. However, a sequence of expressions is not actually a valid expression, so `_` does not match sequences. That's why `1, 2, 3` in `{1,2,3}` does not get matched by `_`.

`{_}`is for the list of 1 element but not the sequence of elements, `{__}` is for a list with any number of elements but not the empty list (0 elements), `{___}` is for any number of elements including empty list.

Here is some code that can help to understand how exactly pattern matching works in `MatchQ`:

```
In[108]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[1],FullForm[_?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[108]= {MatchQ[1,PatternTest[Blank[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),True},True}

```
In[109]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[1],FullForm[{_?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[109]= {MatchQ[1,List[PatternTest[Blank[],NumberQ]]],False}

```
In[101]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1}],FullForm[_?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[101]= {MatchQ[List[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),PatternTest[Blank[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[{1}],False},False}

```
In[102]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1}],FullForm[{_?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[102]= {MatchQ[List[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),List[PatternTest[Blank[],NumberQ]]],{NumberQ[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),True},True}

```
In[103]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1,2,3}],FullForm[_?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[103]= {MatchQ[List[1,2,3],PatternTest[Blank[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[{1,2,3}],False},False}

```
In[110]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1,2,3}],FullForm[{_?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[110]= {MatchQ[List[1,2,3],List[PatternTest[Blank[],NumberQ]]],False}

```
In[104]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1}],FullForm[__?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[104]= {MatchQ[List[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),PatternTest[BlankSequence[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[{1}],False},False}

```
In[105]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1}],FullForm[{__?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[105]= {MatchQ[List[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),List[PatternTest[BlankSequence[],NumberQ]]],{NumberQ[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),True},True}

```
In[96]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1,2,3}],FullForm[__?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[96]= {MatchQ[List[1,2,3],PatternTest[BlankSequence[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[{1,2,3}],False},False}

```
In[97]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1,2,3}],FullForm[{__?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[97]= {MatchQ[List[1,2,3],List[PatternTest[BlankSequence[],NumberQ]]],{NumberQ[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),True},{NumberQ[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit),True},{NumberQ[3],True},True}

```
In[106]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1}],FullForm[___?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[106]= {MatchQ[List[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),PatternTest[BlankNullSequence[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[{1}],False},False}

```
In[107]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1}],FullForm[{___?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[107]= {MatchQ[List[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),List[PatternTest[BlankNullSequence[],NumberQ]]],{NumberQ[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),True},True}

```
In[98]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1,2,3}],FullForm[___?NumberQ]]]
```

> Out[98]= {MatchQ[List[1,2,3],PatternTest[BlankNullSequence[],NumberQ]],{NumberQ[{1,2,3}],False},False}

```
In[99]:= Trace[MatchQ[FullForm[{1,2,3}],FullForm[{___?NumberQ}]]]
```

> Out[99]= {MatchQ[List[1,2,3],List[PatternTest[BlankNullSequence[],NumberQ]]],{NumberQ[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba),True},{NumberQ[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit),True},{NumberQ[3],True},True}

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Isn't documentation clear about `_, __, ___`?

Comment: @Kuba From the documentation I read "_ or Blank[] is a pattern object that can stand for any Wolfram Language expression." I understand "any Wolfram Language expression" as `_ `equal`{_}` because I understand it as any kind of list any kind of number or any kind of other expression.

Comment: Yes `_` matches `{whatever}` but you had `{_}` and wanted it to match `{1,2,3}`. Which is a different thing.

Comment: @Kuba Indeed. The thing to understand here is that `_` matches any valid expression while `__` matches a sequence of expressions. However, a sequence of expressions is not actually a valid expression, so `_` does not match sequences. That's why `1, 2, 3` in `{1,2,3}` does not get matched by `_`